# To display "Enter valid Email Address" if user used three dots after @ symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to display error message if user enter three dots like`steve@gmail.com.co.nz` so after `.co` if user use `.nz` Error should be thrown because user has already entered two dots.
Below is my Email validation which i am using right now

```
var EmailValid = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[A-Za-z0-9'\.\-\s\,\#\]*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})$";
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript get regexp from here

Comment: it is adding too mate..see my question

Comment: Why do you want to reject perfectly valid email addresses? (If you want a real world example, I used to have an address which went `someone@some-campus.some-school.some-county.sch.uk`)

Comment: even i raised the same question to client but you know you have to obey until they are paying you.

Comment: either way, have I solved your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, based on your Regex and the condition that there can be no more than three `.` after the `@` sign:

```
^[\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@[\w-]+\.[\w'\-\s,#\\]*\.?(?:[A-Za-z]{2,3})$
```

Notes:

- I swapped out your `_A-Za-z0-9` for `\w` as it is the same thing.
- I moved the `.` matching out of the quantifiers (i.e., `+` and `*`) as you have a requirement to match between 1-2 max `.`s after the `@` sign.
- I kept most of your required matches for emails, even though I've never seen such symbols used in email endings before. So there may be room for improvement there.

Railroad Diagram:

[image]

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yF2lU0/2)

Comment: @Steve can you provide me an example of cases that do not work? I have linked the Regex101 link with example cases that work and do not work following your use case.